# Trying to building optimised Query for Group and Subgroup for a user

Tags: mysql

i am trying to write the Query for three things .My table structure is like that

You can see Schema at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56c2d/1

I am trying to write the query in MYSQL

```
user:-  table
    user_id
    user_fname
```

This is User tabke which will save User Information

```
group:- "group" and "subgroup" is maintain in same table using column "group_parent_group_id"
    group_id
    group_title
    group_parent_group_id(INT)
```

This is group table which will save Group and Subgroups

```
user_group: table
    user_group_id
    user_group_user_id
    user_group_group_id
```

This ill store both User and Group relation using their Id

I am trying to write the Query for three things. Fetching Users Groups, Subgroups

1) Query to fetch list of All Groups for User Register. Query is gelow and is giving error

Query:

```
select user.id, user.user_fname, group.group_id, group.group_title 
from `user` 
inner join user_group on user_group.user_group_user_id =  user.user_id 
inner join group on group.group_id = user_group.user_group_group_id   
where user_group.user_group_user_id = 1 and user_group.group_parent_group_id = 0
```

2) I am Looking the query to fetch all subgroups(For Whom user is already Register) for Group Id 1,2 or 1

3) I am Looking the query to fetch all subgroups(For Whom user is Not Register yet) for Group Id 1,2 or 1. Ideal is for giving him randomly suggest a subgroup to add

Please Help. I am a newbie in DB :(

Comment: in code tag, do not put your question text.

Comment: i have try to remove it.but is not goes. it is coming automatically  :(

Comment: I have edited it to remove the code tags around the normal text. However you talk about users who are registered or not registered but from your description I am not sure how you determine whether they are registered or not.

Comment: well, if user register for a group/subgroup. they will have a entry in user_group table

Comment: Can you put up your actual table declares and some sample data please.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56c2d/1

Comment: And from those samples, what do you want as the output from the 3 queries?

Comment: Well, the idea is 
 i want to Load "suggestion" for a User. I want to show "Subgroups" list as a suggestion so that user can add them

 Just like you have saw in FACEBOOK. Friends Suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is probably failing as you have a table called group, which is a reserved word. You can use back tics to delimit the name to get away with this (as follows) but it would be a better idea to change the table name.

```
SELECT user.id, user.user_fname, `group`.group_id, `group`.group_title 
FROM `user` 
INNER JOIN user_group ON user_group.user_group_user_id =  user.user_id 
INNER JOIN `group` ON `group`.group_id = user_group.user_group_group_id   
WHERE user_group.user_group_user_id = 1 
AND user_group.group_parent_group_id = 0
```

EDIT updated for queries I think the OP requires.

First query will get a list of all the groups (ones that have no parent group id) that a user (in this case id 28) is a member of

```
SELECT y2m_user.user_id, y2m_user.user_first_name, y2m_group.group_id, y2m_group.group_title 
FROM y2m_user 
INNER JOIN y2m_user_group ON y2m_user_group.user_group_user_id =  y2m_user.user_id 
INNER JOIN y2m_group ON y2m_group.group_id = y2m_user_group.user_group_group_id   
WHERE y2m_user.user_id = 28
AND y2m_group.group_parent_group_id = 0
```

This query will get a list of all the sub groups (ones where the parent group id is greater than 0) that a user (in this case id 28) is a member of

```
SELECT y2m_user.user_id, y2m_user.user_first_name, y2m_group.group_id, y2m_group.group_title 
FROM y2m_user 
INNER JOIN y2m_user_group ON y2m_user_group.user_group_user_id =  y2m_user.user_id 
INNER JOIN y2m_group ON y2m_group.group_id = y2m_user_group.user_group_group_id   
WHERE y2m_user.user_id = 28
AND y2m_group.group_parent_group_id > 0
```

This query will get a list of all the sub groups (ones where the parent group id is greater than 0) that a user (in this case id 28) is **NOT** a member of

```
SELECT y2m_user.user_id, y2m_user.user_first_name, y2m_group.group_id, y2m_group.group_title 
FROM y2m_user 
CROSS JOIN y2m_group
LEFT OUTER JOIN y2m_user_group ON y2m_user_group.user_group_user_id =  y2m_user.user_id  AND y2m_group.group_id = y2m_user_group.user_group_group_id  
WHERE y2m_user.user_id = 28
AND y2m_group.group_parent_group_id > 0
AND y2m_user_group.user_group_id IS NULL
```

Please excuse any typos as not tested (with your test data there are no sub groups).

Comment: My table is y2m_table. I have remove prefix just here

Comment: @user2450837: in this case, say so in the question, and tell what the error message actually is. As things stand, a cursory glance at the query yields kickstart's answer.

Comment: @Denis. The above query is return empty result even we have entry in that table

Comment: @i am able to run the above Sql Successfully. Thanks @Kickstart. But my actual query is how we can trace the list of register and unregister Subgrops for a user ?

Comment: @user2450837 , I have added some suggested queries to my answer.

Comment: Can i use this query .   SELECT  *
FROM    `y2m_group`
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  null 
        FROM    `y2m_user_group`  
        WHERE   `y2m_user_group`.`user_group_group_id` = y2m_group.`group_id` 
        )
 and `y2m_group`.group_id In(6,7,8)
 and `y2m_group`.group_parent_group_id =1   ?

Comment: This will Load the subgroups of Group 6,7,8 which Users has not Registered. Since we want to load suggestion of that Subgroup only for Registered for that Group

Comment: I have a dislike of corelateed sub queries as they often perform very badly. Generally better to use a JOIN. My last bit of SQL should do the same as it joins the user table against the group table, getting all the groups, then uses a LEFT JOIN to see if that user is a member of that group. Then only returns those where no record was found on the LEFT JOIN (hence only those they are not a member of).

Comment: Ok, how about this. i have use your query with IN. SELECT y2m_user.user_id, y2m_user.user_first_name, y2m_group.group_id, y2m_group.group_title 
FROM y2m_user 
CROSS JOIN y2m_group
LEFT OUTER JOIN y2m_user_group ON y2m_user_group.user_group_user_id =  y2m_user.user_id  AND y2m_group.group_id = y2m_user_group.user_group_group_id  
WHERE y2m_user.user_id = 28
AND y2m_group.group_parent_group_id In (6,7,8)
AND y2m_user_group.user_group_id IS NULL

Comment: If you want to know which groups they are not a member of but which have parent groups of 6, 7 or 8 then that should do it.